# how to deploy the SharePoint application from one server to another server?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, custom-masterpage, backup

I created one SharePoint application with several web parts, List, blogs,Search, sub site,etc.I need to deploy this application to another server. Whether Backup and Restoration will work perfectly or we need to create the application by programmatically for deployment. I google it but I can't find any Valid solution.

Comment: is it a template or solution created via visual studio? you deployed it as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy option is to take a Site Collection Backup from staging server and restore it in Production.

Then install the Visual Studio solution.

Recommended approach is you create all these objects (List/Pages/Adding webparts to pages/Content Types) using your Visual Studio solution.